# Solutions that are part of the Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

Why do we omit solutions that do not converge at $\pm\infty$ from the physical Hilbert space, what is the argument for us being allowed to do so?

Comment: Who says that we are removing these solutions (solutions to *what*?), and in what context? Perhaps also have a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/331976/50583 and its linked questions.

Comment: I second the questions of the previous comment, but it's worth noting that in most situations where you're dealing with functions and you want to make them converge at $\pm \infty$, the ones that do not converge aren't even in the Hilbert space, as this space is usually $L^2$ or some extension of it to tempered distributions

Comment: @ACuriousMind Shankar when solving problems in his book Principles of quantum mechanics. I can give plenty of examples from there, the most recent one that kinda made me ask why( he probably did explain it somewhere but I have since forgotten where and can't find it) is on page 192.
https://imgur.com/a/nB3grCe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are only interested in solutions $\psi(x)$ which are normalizable, i.e.
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\psi(x)|^2 \text{d}x = 1.$$

If $\psi(-\infty)$ or $\psi(+\infty)$ diverge,
then this normalization would not be possible.

---

**Edit**:

Actually the above is nearly true (for practical physical purposes),
but not completely true (in strict mathematical sense).
There are some pathological counter-examples, where $\psi(x)$
is normalizable, but $\psi(-\infty)$ and $\psi(+\infty)$ are divergent.
See question "[Normalizable wavefunction that does not vanish at infinity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331976/normalizable-wavefunction-that-does-not-vanish-at-infinity)"
and its answers.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm... ok we are interested in those solutions but why aren't they part of the hilbert space, or by definition only normalizable solutions are part of it?

Comment: Actually I answered my question from here:https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/307998/